# Regular expression matching in content

Tags: php, regex

I want to match the following string with a regular expression:

```
$string ="test string [% code content ='test content' class ='myclass' %]";
```

I want to extract the class and content from this string in percentage braces. Iam using this pattern for matching

```
$regex_pattern = "/[% ?.*](.*)[\/%]/";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$content,$matches);
```

but not getting the output that I require.

Comment: Okay, so what is the output you require?

Comment: Btw, you must escape the `[` if you want to match it, i.e. `/\[%(.*?)%\]/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex to capture `contents` and `class` values regardless of their positions inside the `[% ... %]`:

```
(?:content|class)\s*='([^']+?)'(?=(?:(?!\[\%|\%\]).)*?\%\])
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX5gR3/4).

```
<?php
    $re = "/(?:content|class)\\s*=\\s*'([^']+?)'(?=(?:(?!\\[\\%|\\%\\]).)*?\\%\\])/"; 
    $str = "test string [% code content ='test content' class ='myclass' %]"; 
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    echo $matches[1][0] . "\n";
    echo $matches[1][1] . "\n";
?>
```

Here is a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMLWtrb2JCX0JjdUk).

Output:

```
test content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
myclass
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use `\G` anchor since you're trying to grab some contents from a block `[%..%]`.

```
(?:\[%|(?<!^)\G).*?(content|class)\s*='([^']*)'(?=(?:(?!\[%|%\]).)*?%])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fA7xB8/6)

**Example:**

```
$s = "content ='outside content' test string [% code content ='test content' class ='myclass' %]";
preg_match_all("~(?:\[%|(?<!^)\G).*?\K(content|class)\s*='([^']*)'(?=(?:(?!\[%|%\]).)*?%])~", $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => content ='test content'
            [1] => class ='myclass'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => content
            [1] => class
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test content
            [1] => myclass
        )

)
```